# Is there a way to deflate & map bit-mapped database columns into scala objects via slick

Tags: scala, slick, bit-fields, scala-macros

This is in continuation to the following post:

[How to combine multiple columns in one case class field when using lifted embedding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18572084/how-to-combine-multiple-columns-in-one-case-class-field-when-using-lifted-embedd/22490376#22490376)

I am a great fan of bit fields, wants to use this logic in a project  where I am using slick-macros. Unfortunately slick-additions is not fully updated to slick 2.0, there is a branch dedicated which is not stable, in fact won't even compile. I wanted to test above logic directly but ended up with errors below:

As per the post above:

```
trait Bitmasked {
  type Value
  def bitFor: Value => Int
  def forBit: Int => Value
  def values: Iterable[Value]
  def longToSet: Long => Set[Value] =
    bm => values.toSeq.filter(v => 0 != (bm & (1 << bitFor(v)))).toSet
  def setToLong: Set[Value] => Long =
    _.foldLeft(0L){ (bm, v) => bm + (1L << bitFor(v)) }

  implicit lazy val enumTypeMapper: BaseTypeMapper[Value] =
    MappedTypeMapper.base[Value, Int](bitFor, forBit)
  implicit lazy val enumSetTypeMapper: BaseTypeMapper[Set[Value]] =
    MappedTypeMapper.base[Set[Value], Long](setToLong, longToSet)

  implicit lazy val getResult: GetResult[Value] =
    GetResult(r => forBit(r.nextInt))
  implicit lazy val getSetResult: GetResult[Set[Value]] =
    GetResult(r => longToSet(r.nextLong))
}

/** Mix this class into a subclass of Enumeration to have it usable as a
  * column type in a Slick Table. */
trait BitmaskedEnumeration extends Bitmasked { this: Enumeration =>
  def bitFor = _.id
  def forBit = apply(_)
}

object Role extends Enumeration with BitmaskedEnumeration {
  type Role = Value
  val Editor, Moderator, Administrator, Usermoderator, Usermoderator2, Partner, PremiumPartner, CorporatePaid = Value
}
```

.

```
[error] C:\git\slick-macros\database\src\main\scala\model\Database.scala:9: object BaseTypeMapper is not a member of package scala.slick.lifted
[error] import slick.lifted.{BaseTypeMapper, MappedTypeMapper}
[error]        ^
[error] C:\git\slick-macros\database\src\main\scala\model\Database.scala:56: not found: value Role
[error]   import Role._
[error]          ^
[error] C:\git\slick-macros\database\src\main\scala\model\Database.scala:61: not found: type Role
[error]   case class Member(login: String, rights: UserRights, roles: Role,  addr: Address, company: Company, manager: Option[Member]) {
[error]                                                               ^
[error] three errors found
[error] (database/compile:compile) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 17 s, completed Mar 18, 2014 1:18:30 PM
```

Is there a way to bit-mapped database columns deflated and mapped?

say, a user is an Editor when the value is 1 (binary 0001), Moderator when the value is 2 (binary 0010) and both Editor and Moderator when the value is 3 (binary 0011). I want a way to deflate this and set the flags in Scala.

Thank You,
shashi

Answer (score 0):

Please read the documentation on mapping custom types. http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.0/userdefined.html#scalar-types